# Using SQL Express instance in VSTS hosted build agent

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Using visualstudio online build services I'm trying to run some integration tests that require database access. From my research I can see that a SQL Express database is installed on the hosted build agent (http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2013/02/03/tfs---get-list-of-software-installed-on-build-agent.aspx)

Nevertheless when I run my tests I get the "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'" error. I'm using .\SQLEXPRESS and Integrated Security=True with my connection string.

Does anyone know if there is a specific user with admin privileges that you can use to create databases on the build hosted agent?

For some project specific requirements I can't use localdb, so I'm trying to use SQL Express on the build so I can use the same connection string on my pc and on the build.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: I recommend you use Azure SQL Server or setup a private build agent that can connect to your SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference is for the old hosted XAML agent, which is not the same thing as the current hosted agent. Hosted XAML build controllers are gone.

Per the current hosted agent [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted), SQL isn't installed on the hosted agents. If you want to run your integration tests, you'll need to provision your own server with the appropriate tools installed.

Comment: You are right, at the end I settle for a localdb connection. I have one step that run the sqllocaldb create command and another one that run the migrations and everything is working fine. Thank you very much